# transform Json to Class using objectMapper.readValue using generics

Tags: java, generics, objectmapper

I want to transform a json to an instance of Object.

I m using Jackson jsonMapper that s takes in paramater the .class of the object. I want to get this functionality using generics

Here is my class :

```
public class Utils<T> {

    private final Class<T> type;

    public Utils(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Class<T> getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}
```

I am trying to do the following :

```
objectMapper.readValue(new TreeTraversingParser(jsonObject), getType());
```

what I need is to access to the `<T>`.class and this is not working .. how may I do that

Comment: Does passing a [`TypeReference`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html)  instead of a `Class` as the second argument to `readValue` let you do what you want?

Comment: What's not working?